# Where to catch IntentService Exception to avoid crash due to UnhandledException?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a native Xamarin Android app which throws an Exception in an IntentService. The callstack is useless for determining where I'm standing in the excecution when the Exception happens (IntentServices run in a separate thread I guess?).

Is there any good place in Xamarin apps to catch Exceptions like these?

PS: if you are wondering why don't I just put a catch within the IntentService, it's because it sits inside a 3rd party lib. *I could* inject my own class and avoid this, but I'd rather just use the Lib as-is and find a propper place to catch this.

Answer (score 3):

I would subclass the `IntentService` from your 3rd-party library and try/catch in the service method overrides as letting it percolate to the `Application` is a real code smell....

Otherwise you would need to subclass `Application` and add an `AndroidEnvironment.UnhandledExceptionRaiser` hander:

```
[Application]
public class MyApplication : Application
{
    public MyApplication(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer) { }
    public MyApplication() { }

    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();
        AndroidEnvironment.UnhandledExceptionRaiser += HandleEventHandler;
    }

    void HandleEventHandler(object sender, RaiseThrowableEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Exception)
        {
            case AndroidException ae:
                Log.Error("SO", ae.ToString());
                Log.Error("SO", ae.StackTrace);
                Log.Error("SO", ae.InnerException?.ToString());
                Log.Error("SO", ae.InnerException?.StackTrace);
                e.Handled = true; //?????
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The issues at the app level *is* the exception from your service? If so are you just going to bury it (e.Handled = true)? Otherwise what are you going to do, flag it handled or not?

Of course this assumes that you are not using a crash reporter at the application level, which IMHO is just wrong...

Comment: Thanks. The codebase is already quite smelly (there are several reasons why it took ya _months_ to realize this particular issue). It gives me a bit of a sour taste, but I think I'll try subclassing Application and see if we can catch it there (we may have other random unhandleds that may be causing crashes that we could catch there; our crash reports are lacking details).

Comment: Update: nope, turns out I already had those handlers in my `MyApp : Application` class, but somehow it's not being handled by it and instead crashes the app.. So I ended up extending/reimplementing the class from the library that throws that exception internally and handled it there. I don't like having to mess with 3rd party's code, but "what's one more stripe on a tiger?" seems to be the motto on this project.

Comment: @SebastiánVansteenkiste `what's one more stripe on a tiger` LOL.... soon you might be releasing a confused zebra ;-)

Comment: @SebastiánVansteenkiste Just out of curiosity, do you have the exact Exception that is being thrown

Comment: It's a custom exception class used by the 3rd party library. I was hoping to find a good place to put a "catch" on our solution, but we had no luck, since for some reason we aren't getting it as a call to neither of the handlers in our Application class either.

Comment: @SebastiánVansteenkiste Can you add to your question the error from `logcat` that is being reported by the OS

Comment: Sadly no, logcat's not cooperating. Without disclosing any sensitive information though, I can tell you it's because a Push Notification Service handler's trying to connect to a URL that doesn't exist (or is not responding). The deepest exception we're capturing is `Java.Lang.RuntimeException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)`, that bubbles up within the library and then is rethrown as a custom exception (PushNotificationException) in an IntentService. Thankfully I have _some_ access to that library's code, so I could reimplement the IntentService.